# SAS help - median of values in an array

Tags: sas

I am relatively new to SAS but have done a fair amount of programming over the years. I am at a loss on how to accomplish a task in SAS that I feel I would be able to do relatively easily in other platforms. I have an input table similar to this:

| City | _1988 | _1989 | _1990 | _1991 | _1992 | _1993 | _1994 | _1995 | _1996 | _1997 | _1998 | _1999 | _2000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Columbus | 438866 | 437148 | 16082 | 475843 | 224411 | 411569 | 658459 | 174208 | 592418 | 31664 | 312374 | 242830 | 342950 |
| Fargo | 11218 | 7402 | 35574 | 14765 | 64727 | 29492 | 104541 | 616 | 57864 | 73451 | 96251 | 78803 | 34743 |
| Santa Fe | 10608 | 31531 | 46163 | 28215 | 62608 | 52576 | 55674 | 43339 | 34896 | 77851 | 41304 | 31308 | 60306 |
| Poughkeepsie | 2184 | 15642 | 13505 | 9279 | 22796 | 6458 | 3279 | 4458 | 19672 | 17610 | 2672 | 11454 | 1072 |
| Montpelier | 1428 | 671 | 520 | 5453 | 5468 | 2117 | 2802 | 5847 | 3165 | 6204 | 1832 | 5357 | 5499 |
| Waco | 12527 | 695 | 44426 | 61651 | 83997 | 12811 | 50570 | 15022 | 86732 | 38541 | 45292 | 120719 | 17969 |
| Nashville | 359806 | 249811 | 422314 | 151319 | 466174 | 107335 | 315576 | 571273 | 195685 | 230626 | 194663 | 11060 | 545940 |
| Billings | 49694 | 37415 | 38602 | 79238 | 65260 | 18497 | 8976 | 81148 | 71326 | 108760 | 43740 | 48110 | 32106 |
| Pensacola | 4501 | 9682 | 19061 | 14731 | 4623 | 16106 | 13419 | 47607 | 9198 | 25003 | 39303 | 45146 | 24143 |
| Trenton | 40341 | 21210 | 4162 | 57773 | 16937 | 60495 | 21508 | 80819 | 27349 | 65088 | 65815 | 66308 | 38151 |

I would like to find the median of all the differences in values for each city.

The basic logic is I need to obtain the median of all the values in the array "difference" in the pseudo-code below.

```
 for i = 1988 to 2000

      for j = i+1 to 2000

           difference(i,j) = value year_i - value year_j

      end

 end
```

I wish I could paste my sample code here, but I am basically at a point of writers block where what I have produced is so far off that it is of no use. I don't necessarily need someone to write the entire code for me but am hoping somebody can send me down the right path. I feel like this shouldn't be that hard, but I am at a loss . . .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, are you sure you want to compute all pairwise differences? It does not seem to make much sense: maybe the year-to-year differences? If so, you might 1/ convert to long form (PROC TRANSPOSE) and compute the median by group with a PROC UNIVARIATE. Or 2/ use an array in a datastep, and use the `median(of ...)` syntax (works with `mean`, not entirely sure with `median`, my SAS is rusty).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I do want to calculate all pairwise differences (I know it seems strange).

Comment: So for each City you want to calculate the median of the upper triangle created by getting negative of the increase in amount as time increases?

Comment: Take a smaller sample (2 or 3 citys and 3 years) and show the input and desired output.

Comment: Do expect the results to be  Columbus ->  57,238.5 Fargo -> -23,940.5 ?

Comment: Do you just want to median year over year decrease for each City? That is the median of N-1 differences instead of the median of whole triangle of difference?  So Columbus -> -49,201.0  and Fargo -> -5885.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely following what you're trying to do here, but I think this will get you going.

First, I create the temp data with pairwise differences as you request. Then I use the Proc Summary to calculate the median across city and year.

Feel free to ask.

```
/* sample data */
data have;
input City :$12. _1988 - _2000;
infile datalines dlm = '|';
datalines;
Columbus    |438866|437148|16082 |475843|224411|411569|658459|174208|592418|31664 |312374|242830|342950 
Fargo       |11218 |7402  |35574 |14765 |64727 |29492 |104541|616   |57864 |73451 |96251 |78803 |34743  
Santa Fe    |10608 |31531 |46163 |28215 |62608 |52576 |55674 |43339 |34896 |77851 |41304 |31308 |60306  
Poughkeepsie|2184  |15642 |13505 |9279  |22796 |6458  |3279  |4458  |19672 |17610 |2672  |11454 |1072   
Montpelier  |1428  |671   |520   |5453  |5468  |2117  |2802  |5847  |3165  |6204  |1832  |5357  |5499   
Waco        |12527 |695   |44426 |61651 |83997 |12811 |50570 |15022 |86732 |38541 |45292 |120719|17969  
Nashville   |359806|249811|422314|151319|466174|107335|315576|571273|195685|230626|194663|11060 |545940 
Billings    |49694 |37415 |38602 |79238 |65260 |18497 |8976  |81148 |71326 |108760|43740 |48110 |32106  
Pensacola   |4501  |9682  |19061 |14731 |4623  |16106 |13419 |47607 |9198  |25003 |39303 |45146 |24143  
Trenton     |40341 |21210 |4162  |57773 |16937 |60495 |21508 |80819 |27349 |65088 |65815 |66308 |38151  
;

/* pairwise differences in long format */
data temp;
   set have;
   array y1(i) _1988 - _2000;
   array y2(j) _1988 - _2000;

   do over y1;
      do over y2;
         year1 = input(compress(vname(y1), , 'kd'), 8.);
         val1  = y1;

         year2 = input(compress(vname(y2), , 'kd'), 8.);
         val2  = y2;

         diff = val1 - val2;

         if i ne j then output;
      end;
   end;

   drop _:;
run;

/* calculate median */
proc summary data = temp nway;
   class city year1;
   var diff;
   output out = want(drop = _:) median =;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 13-element array to hold the year values. And a 13x13 temporary array to hold the differences. Then `median(of ARRAY(*))` to get the median.

```
* create the sample data;
data have;
    input City $ _1988 _1989 _1990 _1991 _1992 _1993 _1994 _1995 _1996 _1997 _1998 _1999 _2000;
    datalines;
Columbus 438866 437148 16082 475843 224411 411569 658459 174208 592418 31664 312374 242830 342950
Fargo 11218 7402 35574 14765 64727 29492 104541 616 57864 73451 96251 78803 34743
Santa-Fe 10608 31531 46163 28215 62608 52576 55674 43339 34896 77851 41304 31308 60306
Poughkeepsie 2184 15642 13505 9279 22796 6458 3279 4458 19672 17610 2672 11454 1072
Montpelier 1428 671 520 5453 5468 2117 2802 5847 3165 6204 1832 5357 5499
Waco 12527 695 44426 61651 83997 12811 50570 15022 86732 38541 45292 120719 17969
Nashville 359806 249811 422314 151319 466174 107335 315576 571273 195685 230626 194663 11060 545940
Billings 49694 37415 38602 79238 65260 18497 8976 81148 71326 108760 43740 48110 32106
Pensacola 4501 9682 19061 14731 4623 16106 13419 47607 9198 25003 39303 45146 24143
Trenton 40341 21210 4162 57773 16937 60495 21508 80819 27349 65088 65815 66308 38151
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    * create an array to hold the year variables;
    array years {1988:2000} _1988 - _2000;
    * create a 2-dimensional array to hold the differences;
    array differences {1988:2000,1988:2000} _temporary_;

    do i = 1988 to 20000;
        do j = i + 1 to 2000;
            * calculate the differences as per pseudo-code in question;
            differences(i,j) = years(i) - years(j);
        end;
    end;
    * get median value;
    median_diff = median(of differences(*));
run;
```

Comment: However we have far to many zeros (the diagonal and everything below). You may fix this by allocating a one dimensional array of dimension n(n-1)/2 and fill it with the differences.

Comment: Since you made a temporary array you need to reset it to missing on each observation.